# JFrame using one component on two different panels makes it dissapear

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Basically I have two panels and one label. I want this label to show in the exact same position on both panels(I'm using the card layout). But when I use the same component it doesn't show up on either panel, but it does if it's only being used on one panel. Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, without code example showing what did you try.

Comment: Surely you don't need code? I declared one JLabel. I have to panels; panel 1 and panel 2. I wan't this label to show up on both panels without having to have two separate labels. but when I use just one label to show up on both panels it dissapears on both.

Comment: I don't understand your talking.

Comment: One component, two panels. The one component only doesn't show if i place it on panel1 and panel2, it only shows if it is placed on only one panel.

Comment: Which layout do you use?

Comment: You may think your description is clear without code, but your understanding is based on mental context that other people don't have. Even if it doesn't seem to you that code is necessary, it can often provide others with context to understand what you're talking about. Questions concerning code you've written should *always* include relative parts of the code. I highly recommend that you read [Jon Skeet's blog post about asking good questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. A Swing component can only have 1 parent.

But you might be able to create 2 JLabel objects, and give them the same Model, so they always show/contains the same data.

Comment: Oh ok. It's a pain as I have like 20 Components and I need to use all 20 of them on three different panels. So in total I have to use 60 components, correct?

Comment: It sounds like a waste of resources, but in a usual setting, this is really nothing that needs to be optimized. I dare to say the usual repaint, e.g. when resizing a window, will create many more temporary objects than 60. If your concern is not about performance but consistency, then sharing models is what you'd want.

Comment: It's more about not wanting to have a HUGE list of JFrame components declared xD